# Calculate all possible pairs of items from two lists?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, combinations

I have two arrays:

```
string[] Group = { "A", null, "B", null, "C", null };

string[] combination = { "C#", "Java", null, "C++", null };
```

I wish to return all possible combinations like:

```
{ {"A","C#"} , {"A","Java"} , {"A","C++"},{"B","C#"},............ }
```

The null should be ignored.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

```
Group.Where(x => x != null)
     .SelectMany(g => combination.Where(c => c != null)
                                 .Select(c => new {Group = g, Combination = c})
     );
```

Alternatively:

```
from g in Group where g != null
from c in combination where c != null
select new { Group = g, Combination = c }
```

Comment: Thanks Mehrdad for immediate response.

Comment: Any Idea how to do this efficiently to get permutations not only combinations? (meaning {"A","C#"} and {"C#","A"} will be considered two sepeate items) ?