# How to add add items near to next list

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to make a program like wordlist generator.
I want to add the items on the 2nd list next to each item on the 1st list.
`

```
List<string> list1 = new List<string>() {"tomato", "ball", "icecream", "blue"};

List<string> list2 = new List<string>() { "123", "yellow", "green" };
```

`

```
//Values ​​to be added to Listing 3: tomato123, tomatoyellow, tomatogreen, ball123, ballyellow, ballgreen bla bla bla
```

Comment: [This should almost do what you want](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1328079/calculate-all-possible-pairs-of-items-from-two-lists) but you need to change the `.Select(c => new {Group = g, Combination = c})` to `.Select(c => $"{g}{c}")`. [Example](https://rextester.com/UOJO68846)

Answer (score 3):

To solve your problem, we will iterate over one of the lists, and for every item in it, we will create all the possible combinations with words from the other list. With LINQ, it would look something like this:

```
var list3 = list1.Select(w1 => list2.Select(w2 => w1 + w2)).ToList();
```

The problem is that now `list3` is of type `List<IEnumerable<string>>` because we have a list of combinations for every word in `list1`. To flatten the result, all we need is to change the `Select` projection to a `SelectMany` flattened projection:

```
var list3 = list1.SelectMany(w1 => list2.Select(w2 => w1 + w2)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your requirement it might be useful. Please have a look.

```
 static void AddLists()
    {
        List<string> list1 = new List<string>() { "tomato", "ball", "icecream", "blue" };
        List<string> list2 = new List<string>() { "123", "yellow", "green" };

        var resultList = from l1 in list1
                         from l2 in list2
                         select string.Concat(l1, l2);           
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

My advice would be to create an extension method, instead of a LINQ statement that is difficult to understand: readers will immediately see what it does, it is easier to test and easier to change.

See [extension methods demystified](http://geekswithblogs.net/BlackRabbitCoder/archive/2013/03/08/c.net-little-wonders-extension-methods-demystified.aspx)

```
public static IEnumerable<string> ConcatCombinations(
    this.IEnumerable<string> sequenceA,
    IEnumerable<string> sequenceB)
{
    // TODO: invent a proper name

    foreach (string textA in sequenceA)
        foreach (string textB in sequenceB)
            yield return textA + textB;
}
```

This code is way simpler than any solution using LINQ methods. Anyone will immediately see what it does.

Usage:

```
List<string> list1 = ...
string[] array1 = ...

List<string> concatenated = list1.ConcatCombinations(array1).ToList();
```

If you want to make a more generic method, consider this:

```
public static IEnumerable<TResult> MakeCombinations<TA, TB, TResult>(
    this IEnumerable<TA> itemsA,
    IEnumerable<TB> itemsB,
    Func<TA, TB, TResult> resultSelector)
{
    foreach (TA itemA in itemsA)
        foreach (TB itemB in itemsB)
        {
            TResult result = resultSelector(itemA, itemB);
            yield return result;
        }
}
```

Usage:

```
List<string> list1 = ...
List<string> list2 = ...

List<string> concatenated = list1.ConcatCombinations(list2,

   // parameter ResultSelector: concat every a and b:
   (a, b) => a+b)
   .ToList();
```

Or just change your ConcatCombinations:

```
public static IEnumerable<string> ConcatCombinations(
    this.IEnumerable<string> sequenceA,
    IEnumerable<string> sequenceB)
{
    return sequenceA.MakeCombinations(sequenceB,
        (a, b) => a + b);
}
```

Another completely different example, that shows you the reusability of the code:

```
var maleBallroomDancers = ...
var femaleBallroomDancers = ...

var danceCombinations = maleBallroomDancers.MakeCombinations(femaleBallroomDancers,

    (male, female) => new
    {
        Male = male,
        Female = female,
    })
    .ToList();
```